# Auto-bind selectfield to a store in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to bind a selectfield to a store in sencha-touch.  However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

The field looks like so:

```
{
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            label: 'Gender',
            store: 'GenderStore',
            displayField: 'ItemName',
            valueField: 'Id'
        },
```

and store looks like so:

```
Ext.define('MobileApp.store.Gender', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MobileApp.model.Lookup',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MobileApp.model.Lookup',
        storeId: 'GenderStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',            
            url : '/api/lookup/genders',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    }    
});
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? I thought maybe specifying the storeId would automatically create the store similar to using xtype?  Does the field not bind automatically to the store, or do I need to explicitly create the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your view is requiring the store. Perhaps it does not exist yet (and it needs to so it can find it by ID):

```
requires: ['App.store.MyStore']
```

Comment: Hi, I already have this in my view but I get the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

Comment: I think what is confusing is that there are examples on the net which show the use of a store id in quotes and also without quotes. Also, is the id of the store used and what is specified in the alias for the store? Really confused!...

Comment: Have you specified the store in your controller? If not, the framework will not know what it is. a) make the store. b) specify it in the controller using `stores` config. c) specify it in your view either using `storeId` or just the className as a string.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference, here is a paste of what I have: http://pastebin.com/MFuESLE9

Comment: While since I looked at this but I got it working. The store is now defined in the app.js file and appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

the field

```
     {
        xtype: 'selectfield',
        label: 'Gender',
        store: GenderStore,
        displayField: 'ItemName',
        valueField: 'Id'
    },
```

the store

```
var GenderStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
requires: [
    'MobileApp.model.Lookup',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Rest'
],
autoLoad: true,
model: 'MobileApp.model.Lookup',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',            
    url : '/api/lookup/genders',
    reader: {
       type: 'json',
       rootProperty: 'd'
    },
    root: 'd'

}   
});
```